# Adobe premiere, how do i link two audio clips and one video clip for the purposes of the razor tool?

Tags: premiere, adobe

[image]

So this is what it looks like. I have one video track, three audio tracks. The last audio track is background music. I need to edit the clips to cut out the boring parts. The problem is, I want to kind of be able to hear the background music as I play the video in preview. Anyway So normally what I do is, I press shift, and it allows me to use the razor tool to cut all clips at the same time, then i select and drag things into place. The reason why I can't do that here is, the shift razor tool will cut the background music too. What I need to do is link v1 a1 a2 for the purposes of the razor tool so that i may edit them as if they were one clip, how do I do that? I tried link, but link is grayed out for some reason when I select more than two things. Thank you!

Comment: What about locking the music track (the padlock on the left of the track number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though Michael Tiemanns answer is technically correct, it seems overly complicated given the description of your problem, as nested sequences may cause other problems and inconveniences down the road. So here are two other options that might help you:

### Grouping

Select the three tracks you want to edit, then **right-click** → **group** (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>). The grouped clips will all be selected when you click on one of them. Then you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to cut all clips in the group at the position of your playhead. The problem with this method is that the cut clips will still be grouped together, so if you select one of them, they will all be selected and moved simultaneously. The next option will be more convenient for your workflow:

### Track locks

Click on the lock symbol on the left side of the timeline on the track that holds your background music. This will completely lock all clips on the track, preventing you from accidentally cutting or moving them.

Answer (score 0):

You can make V1 + A1 + A2 into a nested sequence by selecting those three tracks and then right clicking to reveal Nest or by using the menu item Clip > Nest.  Then you can use the razor tool on the nested sequence without using shift.  Chop and rearrange to your heart's delight.

Comment: it didn't work. I selected v1 a1 a2, went clip->nest, used the razor tool on one of the three layers, and only one layer was cut. https://i.gyazo.com/45f1fed771ddaa5055f5641827c85f7c.png

Comment: I forgot how schizophrenic is Premiere Pro when it comes to audio.  MortizLost gives a better answer, including one I would have suggested next: the Track Lock.  I think it may also be possible to link clips (as opposed to merely grouping them), but again, Premiere Pro's incoherent design might again foil that idea because it tries overly hard to apply special-case logic to cases that could be seen as general solutions.